# Как узнать оперативную память занятую процессом

Tags: linux

Доброго времени суток!
Вопрос такой, надо узнать оперативую память занятую процессом по PID. Желательно командой, и желательно, что бы результат выводился только в виде занятой памяти без посторонней информации.

Comment: А что такое "оперативная память, занятая процессом"? Если он сидит в свопе, то памяти не занимает? Если про адреса, то dll включать или нет? Ну а насчёт "без посторонней информации" -- так уберите её, textutils предоставляют для этого массу средств. (Если есть затруднения с этим -- напишите какая часть вывода какой команды вас устроит)

Comment: Без посторонней информации желательно, но не обязательно! Я и сам могу обрезать её, мне бы знать как получить эту память!  
А что касается того, что такое "оперативная память, занятая процессом". Такая ситуация, например написал программу в ней содержится массив 100 элементов типа long, 1 переменная long занимает 4 байта, 4*100=400 соответственно программа скушает 400 байт оперативной памяти. Отсюда возникает вопрос, как её отследить при запуске программы зная PID?  
Я пишу скрипт который получает данные о процессе, т.е такие команды как top не подходят!

Comment: Видимо вам надо обрабатывать адреса из 2-х строк файла /proc/<PID>/maps  

Первая строка [heap] - это динамичеки выделенная память, а вторая [stack].


Только учтите ограничения на права доступа.

Comment: @avp там ещё и другие псевдофайлы есть, например statm

Comment: Про формат stat и statm информации (по крайней мере в man 5 proc) нет. А вот status м.б. полезен. Возможно им и надо пользоваться.

Comment: А сами stat и statm есть? Я не знаю, насколько procfs устоялась, и чем она реализуется

Comment: Есть    

    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/tst$ cat /proc/self/statm
    1376 175 147 13 0 67 0
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/tst$ cat /proc/self/stat
    2281 (cat) R 1524 2281 1524 34816 2281 4202496 246 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 20 0 1 0 1233517 5636096 175 18446744073709551615 4194304 4247204 140733970300128 140735399556984 139676873598112 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 17 2 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: `statm  Предоставляет информацию о состоянии памяти в страницах, как единицах измерения. Вот комментарии  по
                     колонкам в файле:
                      size       общий размер программы
                      resident   размер резидентной части
                      share      разделяемые страницы
                      trs        текст (код)
                      drs        данные/стек
                      lrs        библиотека
                      dt         "дикие" (dirty) страницы`

Comment: Понятно. 

Похоже что status, stat и statm содержат частично "пересекающиеся" данные. В status они представленные "в читаемом человеком" виде (много строк вида name: value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе у top есть пара полезных опций, например

```
top -b -n 1 -p 1184
```

выведет один раз информацию о процессе 1184 и завершится. Но все равно он читает данные из /proc, поэтому лучше и удобнее смотреть там

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов частичного ответа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    ifstream ifs("/proc/self/maps", ifstream::in);
    while (ifs.good()) {
        string s;
        getline(ifs, s);
        cout << s << endl;
    }
}
```

`man 5 proc`

Comment: Я не на си делаю скрипт, расскажите поподробнее о команде! /proc/self/maps

Comment: Это не команда, а файл. Точнее псевдофайл. Как я понял, `man 5 proc` вы не набирали. Там расписано. Кстати, если вы будете смотреть /proc/self какой-то командой, то у вас параметры будут относится к процессу этой команды (или shell, если это не внутренняя команда шелла). Кстати, размер виртуальной памяти процесса находится в /proc/self/stat

Answer (score 1):

Есть очень продвинутый **htop**, я бы использовал его.

Еще полезные найденные команды:

```
ps axo %mem,comm,pid,euser | sort -nr | head -n 10

ps auxf | sort -nr -k 4 | head -10
```